# Angular Heroku You have to be inside an angular-cli project in order to use the build command

Tags: angular, heroku, angular-cli

I am trying to deploy NodeJs + Angular app to Heroku. And I get the error ***You have to be inside an angular-cli project in order to use the build command***.

I have a folder structure as in the screenshot below.

[image]

And package.json in main folder.
[image]

Then I try ***git push heroku master***. I seem to install angular cli dependency and then run the ng build, but still an error appears.

[image]

Comment: First, you shouldn't have two package.json files. You only need the one in the root directory. Second, you don't need to specifically install Angular CLI to build the project. `@angular/cli` should be listed as a devDependency

Comment: Once pushed, you should be able to execute `ng build --prod` as part of your `build` command in package.json. If you're using Angular Universal, that will most likely include the standard `ng build` command, but also a `prerender` and `ng run` of your server configuration.

Comment: According to heroku docs angular cli should be dependency

Comment: I've deployed probably a dozen Angular 4+ apps to Heroku, and I've never listed the CLI as a dependency to be bundled with the application. It's only required to compile the code, you wouldn't want that added to any of the bundles that are served.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved my problem by adding NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false.

### **From heroku docs**

*If you need access to packages declared under devDependencies in a different buildpack or at runtime, then you can set NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false or YARN_PRODUCTION=false to skip the pruning step.*
[docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#customizing-the-build-process)